# Overriding spring security actuator without loosing configurable endpoints

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to secure endpoints `Actuators` inside `Spring Boot` project. However instead using ready-to-run `Spring Security` configuration for `Actuators`:

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: true
    role: ADMINISTRATOR
```

*That too easy* I need to plug `Actuators` with our custom security (here `CAS` SSO).

First try it was to add `context-path` for `Actuators`:

```
management:
  security:
    enabled: true
    role: ADMINISTRATOR
  context-path: /management
```

And update my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    http.authorizeRequests()..antMatchers("/management/**").hasRole(Role.ADMINISTRATOR.toString());
    ...
}
```

It works but I must hardcode `Actuators` `context-path`, so when I want to update `management.context-path` I have to update my security.

I know it's possible to retrieve value of `management.context-path` but how to manage it when value equals `""`?

You can answer me to `@Autowired` `EndpointHandlerMapping` and retrieve list of `Actuators` endpoints... Finally I will copy-past same logic as `ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Furthermore `ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` is pointing itself but `ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is inner-static protected class so not possible to disable it without passing parameter `management.security.enabled=false` and that can be strange because your configuration said `management.security.enabled=false` but in reality endpoints are secured...

---

Conclusion

1. Is there a way to override (just a part of) properly `Actuators` security
2. May I miss something and I'm totally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a pending Issue on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1901). For the moment Dave Syer [proposes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1901#issuecomment-63439835):

> I think copy-paste of all the code in there is actually the best
>   solution for now (and set management.security.enabled=false to let
>   Boot know you want to do it yourself).

I have not tested whether a runtime exception will be thrown but I think that you can reuse `ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and save a lot of copy-paste action. At least compiler doesn't complain.

Put your configuration class under package `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure` in your project and extend from `ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. Don't miss all the annotations from `ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. That is the only copy-paste action here because class annotations can not be inherited by subclass.

```
package org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "management.security", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@Order(ManagementServerProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
public class SsoManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //TODO your SSO configuration

}
```

Don't forget to `@Import` your configuration in your `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Ok I did pretty same thing except I did not use `Spring` package I just copied piece of code I need. I will accept answer because it prove that there is no proper way to do what I want. I will track issue on github, I hope a day it will be fixed